# SharePoint 2010 People Search without User Profile Service

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement where i need to enable people search in "My Sites" page from AD without the help of user profile service. Becuase we have a restriction at client/customer side to use User Profile Service. Is there any best way to synchronize the user profile from AD without using User Profile Service?. And also, we need to acheive this out-of-the-box, it means no code solution. Is there anyway to set up people search to index MySites ?

Kindly let me know if my requirement/question is not clear. I will throw some more details.

Thanks in Advance.

Raj.

Comment: You'd probably do better asking Sharepoint questions on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

mySites functionality is closely related to User Profile service. Because of this mySites are not available in SharePoint Foundation.

Without User Profile Service there's no synchronization of User Information except the first access of the user to SharePoint or the first usage of the user in SharePoint (user is used in User Group column).

While user is accessing SharePoint for the first time AD is contacted to get email, display name but there's no sync in the future.